# How are mac address shared between initiater and target?

Tags: networking, switch

If there is a successful TCP/IP connection between two servers in internet layer and the source address and destination mac addresses are attached to the TCP/IP packets, then how are the mac addresses shared between the two servers?

Comment: Please improve your post, isnt clear what are you asking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer has an ip and a network mask, eg.
the ip is 192.168.0.10 and the network mask is 255.255.255.0 (or in CIDR /24).
That means that the first three bytes (triples) are signifying the network and the last byte is identifying the computer in said network.

If the target address is within the same network an arp packet is sent to the broadcast address of the local network, in this case 192.168.0.255, that means to all local addresses.

```
who has 192.168.0.27? Please tell 192.168.0.10, my MAC 01:00:f2:10:21:1d.
```

The computer which has the address answers to the included MAC address and the pairing of MAC and IP addresses is cached for a time , see arp -a.

If the Target ip address is not in the same network (according to your network mask, eg. the target is 8.8.4.4 and there is no specific route then the ip packets are sent to the default gateway which routes them to the target.

Answer (score 0):

If server with IP address **A** needs to communicate to server with IP address **B**, then:

- Server A sends an **ARP** packet asking *What is the MAC of IP address B?*. This packet goes inside a broadcast ethernet frame.
- As the frame is broadcast, it's heard by everybody on the same LAN, so server B answers with its MAC address and additionally B learns the MAC address of A.

A and B populate their ARP table with the correspondence MAC - IP. This entry is kept on the table during a limited time after the last communication between A and B, so the table mantains a reasonable size.